# SQL Select in List A but not in List B

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title would suggest I have a two lists, A and B, for sake of the question lets assume list A is `1,2,3` and list B is `4,5,6`.  My table layout is pretty simple consisting of only two columns `tag_id` and `file_id`.  I would like to come up with a reasonable approach to select `file_id` from this table when `tag_id` is in list A but not in list B.

Here is a sample set of data:

```
tag_id   file_id
1        10
1        20
3        20
2        30
4        30
6        30
```

Thus, the ideal results would be 10, 20

Ordinarily this seems like it would be fairly simple for a query such as below:

```
SELECT `file_id` FROM `file_tags` WHERE `tag_id` IN(%v) AND `tag_id` NOT IN(%v)
```

(Note: The %v just expands an array to a list for SQL)

This, however, will not work as `file_id` is not unique.  It will always match something in the first list and the second list is effectively irrelevant.  In hind sight this makes sense though since it only looks at one row at a time, so much for the easy approach.

Future queries didn't seem to get me much further, but to try working around the single row scope of the previous attempt I tried the following:

```
SELECT `file_id` FROM `file_tags` WHERE `tag_id` IN(%v) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT `file_id` FROM `file_tags` WHERE `tag_id` IN(%v))
```

However, this approach did not seem to work either, instead it returns nothing regardless of input in comparison to the previous example.

This feels like a problem that should be reasonably simple to tackle with SQL, however, I am not sure how to proceed at this point.  I could solve this problem program side and process the data after returning an initial list, but I feel there may still be a better pure SQL solution out there which I have not yet thought of.  Any suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: exists and correlated query? oh wait the lists are subsets of data in the same table?

Comment: are the A and B lists defined on db tables?

Comment: They are not @ Miguel.  This is all within the same table @ xQbert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT `file_id` 
FROM `file_tags` 
WHERE `tag_id` IN(1,2,3) 
  AND `file_id` NOT IN(
      SELECT `file_id` 
      FROM `file_tags` 
      WHERE `tag_id` IN(4,5,6)
  )
```

basically say tag_id is in the first list and the file_id is not in the second list of tag_id's

just change the list values to whatever you need it to be

[SEE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c8704/2)

Comment: This has indeed done the trick, hadn't quite thought of it from this angle yet. I'll accept this answer shortly after playing around with it a bit more.  Thanks!

Comment: @p4plus2 of course! think of it this way... if you say file_id in(some condition) and then on the same column say file_id not in(some other condition) there will be conflicts because some conditions may be met and others not.. its best to filter multiple things on separate columns :)

Comment: I've gone ahead and accepted this answer as it seems to do the trick well as is reasonably flexible too.

Comment: @p4plus2 Thanks for that :) ive answered questions and not gotten a response for over a month on them sometimes lol i'll help you out a bit too!